# Observable event not rendered in Angular2 template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, electron

I am trying to figure out why an observable event is not being rendered in the template. I am trying to help one of my workmates. He is doing an Electron project with Angular 2 and is using JavaScript instead of TypeScript. This is a pain and hopefully we convert it to TypeScript soon.

The variable 'eventEmitter' is bound in the template with the async pipe. I have a 2 sec timer that does the emit of the event. The template does not display anything other than the Hello message. I have put break points in and the timer is firing and the emits are going out. I coded a subscribe and verified that the event does go out and can be received. It is comment out now. Here is my app component:

```
var count = 0;

var eventEmitter = new ng.core.EventEmitter();

(function(app) {

var MessageList =
    ng.core.Component({
            selector: 'message-list',
            template:
            '<p>Hello {{name}}</p>' +
            '<p>{{ eventEmitter | async}}</p>'
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: function() {
                console.log("In MessageList");

                /*       eventEmitter
                 .subscribe(
                 function(data) {
                 return data;
                 },
                 function(err) {
                 console.log("EventEmitter error");
                 },
                 function() {
                 console.log("Completed eventEmitter");
                 }
                 );*/


                setInterval(function() {
                    count++;
                    eventEmitter.emit("Got an event at " + count);
                }, 2000)

                this.name = "Test EventEmitter";
            }
        });

app.StatusPage =
    ng.core.Component({
            selector: 'status-page',
            templateUrl: 'app/statuspage.html',
            directives: [MessageList]
        })
        .Class({
            constructor: function() {

            }
        });

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I think I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Not sure eventEmitter can be rendered like that - it's not like it is of type string, number,... What do you see if you console.log eventEmitter, an object? This docs page, https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html, discussed accessing event payload with parameter $event. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

So I did resolve this problem. The issue was I was getting an Electron ipc message in my angular 2 code and the zone system could not handle a call from another thread.  Because the code was not in the zone, events were not detected. I wrapped the code in a ngzone.